# Outlook: PDF Preview Handler Error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf, preview

Ever since I upgraded to Outlook 2016 my attachment PDF Previewer has stopped working with the message

> This file cannot be previewed because of an error with the following previewer:
>
> **PDF Preview Handler**
>
> To open this file in its own program, double-click it.

[image: screenshot of the error message]

I tried these fixes without any luck:

- Reinstalled the latest Adobe Reader.
- Ran this [registry fix](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7682/how-to-fix-pdf-previews-in-outlook-or-explorer-on-64-bit-windows/).
- [LAN Settings](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1168180)
- [Turning off all previewers and/or enabling PDF Preview Handler](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a1c953f4-33f6-4271-a82b-d76e2c804506/pdf-previwer-in-outlook-2010-after-updating-adobe-reader-x-version?forum=outlook).
- [Cleaning out the TEMP and Cache folders](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/cannot-open-preview-of-pdf-attachment-in-outlook/a68e5aa4-f730-4b5d-b1ca-b8670d679240).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all of the above, a restart did the trick. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

For my user, they had not opened Adobe Reader yet. Opening it and agreeing to all the licensing resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open the registry editor, search for "OutlookSecureTempFolder" copy the Value data and paste it on the explorer url bar + Enter, and highlight and delete all items in this folder

Answer (score 0):

Disabling *Internet Auto Detect* did the trick for me.
For example, on...

- Windows 10 64 bits
- Adobe Acrobat Pro or Adobe Reader DC
- Outlook 2016 (32bits)

...do the following:

> Open Adobe Reader -> Go to Edit menu -> Preferences -> Click Internet -> then Internet Settings -> Click LAN Settings -> Uncheck the box -> “Automatically detect settings" -> Click OK button and close Adobe

Comment: Of course, if that fixes it, you likely have a broken proxy, a broken DNS, or a broken network stack.

Comment: Warning that this changes global settings for your computer's network connection, its not specific to Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

Check Adobe Reader compatibility mode; if you use Office 2016 and an OS like Windows Server 2016 or Windows 10, then select "Run this program in compatibility mode for - Windows 8".

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Open Adobe Reader X or XI  etc ... on Menu > Edit > Preferences > General > Click Select "Default PDF Handler" at the bottom of the screen > Click Apply on the popup > OK.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Adobe Reader, but the install was new and I hadn't yet opened Reader directly to accept the EULA. Once I had done that, the preview in Outlook worked.

Comment: @fixer1234 - I believe the user is suggesting that due to the EULA not being accepted the PDF preview was not working within Outlook

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using Acrobat Pro and Outlook 365. .pdf handler issue. My solution, close outlook, download Adobe Reader DC, then re-do a file association with Acrobat Pro to open the .pdf. File handler icon changed to Reader and opens in Acrobat Pro.